# Creating database on remote SQL Server engine

Tags: sql-server, database, installation, nsis

I need to create one installer which will install components on two different machines. Windows services and web services on "APP Server" and database part on "DB Server". SQL Server 2005/2008 will be present only on DB Server.

I will have to run my installer on APP Server which will create database and will insert some static values in tables though SQL Server is not present there. DB Server and APP Server are in same network

Installer that I can create will do this stuff only when SQL Server is present on the same machine where installer is running. But not satisfies the above case.

Is it possible to implement it in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply a matter of bundling a SQL script with the installer and executing the script by calling sqlcmd with ExecWait.

We can run a script using a trusted connection via:

```
sqlcmd -S _SERVER\_INSTANCE_ -d _DBNAME_ -i _SCRIPT_FILE_
```

Or with a SQL Login:

```
sqlcmd -S _SERVER\_INSTANCE_ -d _DBNAME_ -U _USERNAME_ -P _PASSWORD_ -i _SCRIPT_FILE_
```

For performing actions on remote SQL Server engine native driver is required.In SQL Server 2005 or later the command line client is called sqlcmd.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [visual web developer](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-web-developer-express) to create a database connection from a machine where no SQL Server is installed. See this [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/02/17/creating-a-database-connection-to-a-remote-sql-server-database-within-visual-web-developer.aspx) for reference.